# Overloading c++ operators int/float(..)

Tags: c++, int, operators, overloading

I'm working on operators in C++ now, but i have one problem.  Well I'm trying to overloard int/float operators, I have 2 variables in class

```
class Zespolona{
public:
    float re;
    float im;
}
```

I've done all of my operators but when i do

```
operator int const(){
        this->re = (int)this->re;
        this->im = (int)this->im;
        return *this;
    }
```

then it gets an infinite loop.

My main

```
int main(){
    Zespolona z1;
    z1.re = 1.2;
    z1.im = 34.9;

    z1 = (int)z1;
    cout << z1 << endl;
}
```

What can i do, to get int of two of those variables?

Comment: What do you think `return *this` is doing?

Comment: I'm returning a reference to the object, i think.

Comment: Ok, but what type is it?  And what type have you declared your function as returning?

Comment: @codesyntax `z1 = (int)z1;` what do you want to do? `z1` is an object of `class Zespolona`, how can you write `z1 = (int)z1;`?

Comment: I dont really know if i understand you well, but i think this type is an object and I'm returning it

Comment: @Joe I want to overload my object like an operator+=() is doing z1 += z1 ( <1.2, 34,9 > to <2.4, 69,8> ) I want to change all variables in object to int (<1.2,34,9> to <1,34>) but I don't know if is this possible by z1=(int)z1.

Comment: You're not returning a reference to an object. You're returning a copy of it. *this is a copy since you're de referencing it. This contains the address of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you are trying to achieve. I am guessing one of the following two possibilities:

1) Covert the two floats of your class (`re`, `im`) into integers:
This is rather simple. Since the two members are public you can access them directly:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Zespolona Z1;
    Z1.re = 1.2;
    Z1.im = 34.9;

    std::cout << "Re: " << (int) Z1.re << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Im: " << (int) Z1.im << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program should be:

```
Re: 1
Im: 34
```

Note: When you convert a float to an integer everything after the decimal dot is omitted (at least that is the behavior using g++ under Ubuntu).

If you want the two floats to be private or protected you would have to create methods like `int GetRe()` and `int GetIm()`.

2) Convert the two floats of your class (`re`, `im`) into one integer using the integer conversion operator `operator int const()`. This operator has to return exactly one `int`. For the following example I decided to return the absolute value (magnitude) of the complex number (since your members are called re and im I am guessing the class is used for complex numbers):

```
class Zespolona
{
     public:
         float re;
         float im;

         operator int const()
         {
              return (int) sqrt(re*re + im*im);
         }
};

int main()
{
    Zespolona Z1;
    Z1.re = 1.2;
    Z1.im = 34.9;

    std::cout << "Z1: " << (int) Z1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output should now be:

```
 Z1: 34
```

Note: Again the correct (float) result 34.92... is converted into the integer 34.

The code you mentioned in your questions returns a reference to your class `Zespolona` when you try to convert it into `int`. Thus, the compiler again tries to convert that reference into an `int`. But all it gets is again a reference to `Zespolona`, and so on. Hence, you get an infinite loop.